# jdbc application update sql isnt working for me, any ideas

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public void Update(String name, String mobile, String email, String car, String model, String year, String color, String plate_no, String plateletters,String gear, String km, String date,String licesnse,String status, String notes){
    Connection conn = null;
    try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("connected");
        Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        String ins = "update car"
                + "set Name = '"+name+"' , "
                + "Email = '"+email+"' , "
                + "Car = '"+car+"' , "
                + "Model = '"+model+"' , "
                + "Year = '"+year+"' , "
                + "Color = '"+color+"' , "
                + "Plateno = '"+plate_no+"' , "
                + "Plateletters = '"+plateletters+"' , "
                + "Gearbox = '"+gear+"' , "
                + "Km = '"+km+"' , "
                + "Date = '"+date+"' , "
                + "License = '"+licesnse+"' , "
                + "Status = '"+status+"' , "
                + "Notes = '"+notes+"'  "
                + "where Mobile = '"+mobile+"' ";

        stmt.execute(ins);

    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }

}
```

**i have tried prepared statment and `stmt.executeUpdate(ins);` but nothing workes !!

Please help!**

the error :

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'ahmed' , Email = 'ahmed@hotmail.com' , Car = 'honda' , Model = 'hondaz' , Yea' at line 1

Comment: So why is the PHP tag on this question or the phpMyAdmin come to that

Comment: tag spamming only attract downvotes. You should only tag the language used.

Comment: You have missed the point of using a prepared statement.  With a statement, you use `?` placeholders for the column values, and then you bind Java variables to those placeholders.  The [JDBC trails on prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) is probably where you should go next to see where you went wrong.

Comment: You are missing a space between `car` and `set`, so the actual statement is `update carset Name`, which is a syntax error. But please learn how to correctly use prepared statements as your current code is unsafe as it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you add proper space between elements in your SQL query:

```
 String ins = "update car"
```

should be

```
 String ins = "update car "
```

A good approach to doing this is to write and execute your SQL in your database query tool (SQL developer, phpMyAdmin, whatever) and make sure your syntax is good before trying to re-write it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `preparedStatement` instaed of a `Statement`.

```
 Connection conn = null;
                try{
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                    PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(
                                      "update car "
                                    + "set Name = ? ,"
                                    + "Email = ? ,"
                                    + "Car = ? ,"
                                    + "Model = ? ,"
                                    + "Year = ? ,"
                                    + "Color = ? ,"
                                    + "Plateno = ? ,"
                                    + "Plateletters = ? ,"
                                    + "Gearbox = ? ,"
                                    + "Km = ?,"
                                    + "Date = ?,"
                                    + "License = ?, "
                                    + "Status = ?, "
                                    + "Notes = ?  "
                                    + "where mobile = ?"
                    );
                    pstm.setObject(1, name);
                    pstm.setObject(2, email);
                    pstm.setObject(3, car);
                    pstm.setObject(4, model);
                    pstm.setObject(5, year);
                    pstm.setObject(6, color);
                    pstm.setObject(7, plate_no);
                    pstm.setObject(8, plateletters);
                    pstm.setObject(9, gear);
                    pstm.setObject(10, km);
                    pstm.setObject(11, date);
                    pstm.setObject(12, licesnse);
                    pstm.setObject(13, status);
                    pstm.setObject(14, notes);
                    pstm.setObject(15, mobile);

                    pstm.executeUpdate();

                }catch(SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```